# Wildfly-swarm @NameBinding not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, wildfly, wildfly-swarm, requestfiltering

I encountered a strange problem with my wildfly-swarm application.
I've got an JAX-RS Service, Annotation and RequestFilter defined like this

FooService.java

```
@Path("/foo")
@RequestScoped
@Api(value = "foo")
public class FooService extends BaseService {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @ApiOperation(...)
    @ApiResponses(...)
    @Secured({UserGroup.USER})
    public Response getBar(@ApiParam(...) @QueryParam("id") int id) {
        return Response.ok("bar").build();
    }
}
```

BaseService.java

```
public class BaseService {
   ...
}
```

Secured.java

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secured {
    UserGroup[] value() default {};
}
```

FooFilter.java

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class FooFilter extends BaseService implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As far as I understand FooFilter.filter() should be called everytime GET/foo is requested. With Wildfly 12 everything works just fine, but running my wildfly-swarm app FooFilter.filter() is never invoked. 
Any suggestions why?

Just to be complete, here are my dependencies from my pom file.

> ```
>    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>         <version>7.0</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
>         <exclusions>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
>             </exclusion>
>         </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
>         <artifactId>transactions</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>         <version>${version.mysql}</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what might be the issue.

Are there any errors in the log when running in WF Swarm?

Comment: No errors in any log. :( I just tried to use the <artifactId>transactions</artifactId> of <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId> because I thought, that I forgot some dependency, but also the full profile does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me. I got it working.
I just added

```
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    //Filter
    classes.add(FooFilter.class);
    return classes;
}
```

to my Application class. Wildfly swarm is based an Wildfly 11 and not 12. 11 uses RestEasy 3.0.24 as JAX-RS implementation, 12 uses RestEasy 3.5.

It seems that RestEasy 3.0.24 needs to register a RequestFilter manually, whereas 3.5 does not need to.

Comment: Did you try it without manually specifying the fractions? I have never had to manually register a filter in Swarm.